# Maclaurin series for $ f(x)=a^x$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

[image: questions]

My friend is having trouble with these two questions on his homework. I want to help him out but I am not 100% sure how to do these. I took Calculus 3 a while back so its all old memory to me! 

What are your guys thoughts on how to do these two? Thanks for the help!

Comment: $a^x = e^{x\log a}$

Comment: remember that $a=e^(lna)$ and use series for the e-power where $x$ is replaced by $xlna$

Answer (score 1):

$\log_e\left(a^x\right) = x \log_e\left(a\right)$ so $a^x = e^{x \log_e\left(a\right)}$ and you presumably know that $$e^x =  1 + x +\frac{x^2}{2!}+ \frac{x^3}{3!}+ \cdots$$ so $e^{x \log_e\left(a\right)}$ should not be too difficult.

Similarly with  $a^{-x} = e^{- x \log_e\left(a\right)}$ and half their sum or difference.

Answer (score 1):

The base $e$ representation:  $f(x)=a^x=e^{ln(a^x)}=e^{x \cdot ln(a)}$

The MacLaurin series for $f(y)=e^y$ is $e^y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{k!} $and you can make the substitution $y=x\cdot ln(a)$ since the series for $e^y$ converges everywhere.

You can solve the second part of the problem using the base $e$ representation above and the exponential forms for $sinh(x)$ and $cosh(x)$:

$sinh(y)=\frac{e^{y}-e^{-y}}{2}$

$cosh(y)=\frac{e^y+e^{-y}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

We have $a^x = e^{x \ln a}$, so using the standard expansion $e^x = \sum_n \frac{1}{n!}x^n$ we find:
$$ a^x = \sum_n \frac{(\ln a)^n}{n!} x^n.$$